# Which seeds does the `getAssociatedTokenAddress` function use to determine the associated token account public key?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

The `@solana/spl-token` package contains the `getAssociatedTokenAddress` function which can be used to obtain the address (public key) of an associated token account. Here's an example:

```
const programATAPublicKey = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
  mintPublicKey,
  programPDAPublicKey,
  true,
  program.programId
);
```

I am trying to achieve the same result using the `findProgramAddress` function from the `@project-serum/anchor` package. My problem is that I can't figure out which seeds are used inside `getAssociatedTokenAddress`. For example, I expected the following code to return the associated token account public key:

```
const [programATAPublicKey] =
      await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [mintPublicKey.toBuffer(), programPDAPublicKey.toBuffer()],
        program.programId
      );
```

The result is, however, different. Which seed combination would yield an identical result to whatever is returned from `getAssociatedTokenAddress`?

Comment: If you ctrl/cmd + click on the function in vs code you can actually see what seed combo they are using in that function, its very useful in case theres other functions like these in the future

Comment: @Anoushk In my case cmd + click opens only the interface of the function, is there a shortcut that would show me the source?

Comment: To correct my previous comment - I meant type definition instead of interface.

Comment: Hey @leotron, in that case i would suggest checking the spl token repo
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/f487f520bf10ca29bf8d491192b6ff2b4bf89710/token/js/src/state/mint.ts#L114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to use the source!  Here's the exact code that generates the associated token account address:

```
export async function getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    mint: PublicKey,
    owner: PublicKey,
    allowOwnerOffCurve = false,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): Promise<PublicKey> {
    if (!allowOwnerOffCurve && !PublicKey.isOnCurve(owner.toBuffer())) throw new TokenOwnerOffCurveError();

    const [address] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [owner.toBuffer(), programId.toBuffer(), mint.toBuffer()],
        associatedTokenProgramId
    );

    return address;
}
```

where `ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID` is `"ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL"`.

Taken from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/ad97543192e05e6ecba88fff3b1da08ca523a5b6/token/js/src/state/mint.ts#L156

Comment: Since `getAssociatedTokenAddress` uses the associated token program id to obtain `address`, I assume it's impossible to create a token account with that same `address` from inside a Rust program?

Comment: It's possible -- from within a Rust program, you'll have to call the associated token account program to create the account.

Comment: Do you perhaps know how I would define the token account inside the context in that specific case? Simply using the same seeds wasn't enough, I get the cross-program invocation error when I try it with the address generated by `getAssociatedTokenAddress`.

Comment: If you're talking about doing this within anchor, it seems like they've got a very easy way to do it: https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/pull/790

Answer (score 2):

The [Associated Token Account](https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account#:%7E:text=Finding%20the%20Associated%20Token%20Account,the%20wallet%27s%20associated%20token%20address.) uses the following structure:

```
[
    walletAddress.toBuffer(),
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
    tokenMintAddress.toBuffer(),
],
SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID
```

Where `TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"`
and `SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID = "ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL"`.

Comment: Hey. If you haven't already done so, please commit to the Solana Stackexchange. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126615/solana You could greatly help us reach our goal!